# Array Value split by comma - Exclude space end of each text

Tags: javascript, regex

The below code works fine as expected.

```js
var str = "South Georgia and The South Sandwich Islands,Congo, Democratic Republic,Mauritania,Finland";
var res = str.match(/\w.*?\w(?=,\w|$)/g);
console.log(res)
```

However some of our content creators updated the content with space on end of each value (Ex: `'United States '`) and it's not splitting up.

It combines `United States , United Kingdom`.  Merging of text value with comma should not happen if there's a space on the end of each value.

I'm not sure how to solve this issue. Please provide instruction on this.

```js
var str = "Congo, Democratic Republic,United States ,United Kingdom,Finland";
var res = str.match(/\w.*?\w(?=,\w|$)/g);
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Note that jQuery is a framework primarily intended to amend the DOM. For arrays and regex you just need plain JS. I've retagged the question for you

Comment: Also, try `str.split(/\s*,(?=\S)/)`

Answer (score 2):

You need to include a `\s*` in the lookahead to detect and remove the space, if it exists. Try this:

```js
var str = "Congo, Democratic Republic,United States ,United Kingdom,Finland";
var res = str.match(/\w.*?\w(?=\s*,\w|$)/g);
console.log(res)
```

It's worth noting that relying on user input to be in an exact format is asking for problems. I'd suggest using something like a tag well for this, which will provide the values in a serialisable format which is not ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression

```
/ *,(?! )/
```

will split the string on zero or more spaces followed by a comma, provided the comma is not followed by a space, `(?! )` being a *negative lookahead*.

Using this regex to split the second string given in the question produces the array:

```
[”Congo, Democratic Republic”, “United States“, “United Kingdom”, “Finland“]
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/CkEgxW/2/)